# How to improve the throughput of request_logs on Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, logging

Downloading logs from App Engine is nontrivial. Requests are batched; `appcfg.py` does not use normal file IO but rather a temporary file (in reverse chronological order) which it ultimately appends to the local log file; when appending, the need to find the "sentinel" makes log rotation difficult since one must leave enough old logs for `appcfg.py` to remember where it left off. Finally, Google deletes old logs after some time (20 minutes for the app I use).

**As an app scales, and the log generation rate grows, how can one increase the speed of fetching the logs so that `appcfg.py` does not fall behind?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can increase the per-request batch size of logs. In the latest SDK (1.3.1), check out `google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/appcfg.py` around like 861 (`RequestLogLines` method of `LogsRequester` class). You can modify the "limit" parameter.

I am using 1000 and it works pretty well.